# Can I use local .swp files with neovim-qt?

Tags: neovim-qt

I've found that neovim-qt is storing my .swp files in `AppData/Local/nvim-data/swap` and I was wondering if it's possible to change this to get the standard vim behaviour of creating them locally.

Comment: You can usually set the `directory` option to control this... does it work for nvim?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was unaware of this option, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the goals of Neovim is to provide defaults that work for the majority of its users, and [to avoid users disabling swap files, they changed their default location](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4481#issuecomment-241683244). You can go back to the Vim default with `set directory=.`

BTW you may want to consult `:help nvim-defaults` which lists all default changes that Neovim introduced